# Android ShareScreen - Gmail "cannot attach photo"

Tags: android, kotlin, gmail, share, attachment

I've added a share button to my app and I want it to share two things: a small text blurb and an image. I've used the documentation code (https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) almost verbatim, and it works with my messaging app but not with apps such as gmail and outlook where I get a "cannot attach file" message. The documentation mentioned that for apps such as gmail you might have to use an array so I tried that as well with no luck

Here's what I tried
'

```
            val uri = Uri.parse("https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iKIWgaiJUtss/v2/1000x-1.jpg")
            val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Message")
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, arrayOf("testcc@gmail.com"))
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayOf(uri))
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                type = "image/jpeg"
            }'
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `uri`? How are you obtaining it?

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect this, but basically I'm just trying to get an image based on a url. Eventually, I will do this for an image in my res directory

Comment: `EXTRA_STREAM` does not support `https` as a `Uri` scheme. You need to download the content yourself, then serve using `FileProvider` and use a `content` `Uri` obtained from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.